# Google App Scripts regex body.findText(searchPattern) returns null if new lines

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

Here's a Google Document content:

```
Some text, more text...

<li>
some lines
more lines...
</li>

And more text
```

I would like a `regex` to match:

```
<li>
...
</li>
```

So far it returns `null`. My regex only finds `<li>...</li>`, but not with new lines, although I am using the `(?s)` tag suggested to ensure that `.` includes any character and new lines:

`(?s)<li>(.)*?</li>`

My regex works in https://regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/, so I don't understand it doesn't in Google App Script.

Comment: Regex is badly suited for tasks like this. You should use javascript's DOMParser.

Comment: Yes I know you're right. I thought i could only use the DOMParser in a valid html file, as the content of my Google document will be a mix of a few snippets of code and normal text?

Comment: It doesn't need specifically be valid HTML, just well formed XML. So as long as there's a single root element and the nested contents follow proper XML syntax, it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the text of `<li ...>....</li>` in Google Document.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

In your case, you want to use the pattern of `<li sheet="[a-zA-Z0-9]*">[\s\S]*?<\/li>`, please modify to `<li sheet="[a-zA-Z0-9]*">[\\s\\S]*?<\/li>`. In your case, `<li ...>....</li>` has several paragraphs. (From your sample value, I thought like this.) By this, when the pattern of `const searchPattern = '<li sheet="[a-zA-Z0-9]*">[\\s\\S]*?<\/li>'` is used for `body.findText(searchPattern)`, `null` is returned. If `<li ...>....</li>` is put as one paragraph, `body.findText(searchPattern)` returns `<li ...>....</li>`.

In order to search `<li ...>....</li>` which has several paragraphs, how about the following workaround? The flow of this workaround is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Use `<li sheet=` and `<\/li>` as patterns for searching.
2. Using the pattern of `<li sheet=`, retrieve the begin paragraph of `<li ...>`.
3. Using the pattern of `<\/li>`, retrieve the end paragraph of `</li>`.
4. Retrieve the texts between the retrieved begin and end paragraph.
5. This cycle is continued until all `<li ...>....</li>` values are searched.

#### Sample script:

```
function parseLists(body) {
  // var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  // var body = doc.getBody();

  var pattern1 = "<li sheet=";
  var pattern2 = "<\/li>";
  var range1 = body.findText(pattern1);
  var res = [];
  while (range1) {
    var temp = {};
    var p1 = range1.getElement().getParent();
    temp.startIndex = body.getChildIndex(p1);
    var range2;
    if (p1) {
      range2 = body.findText(pattern2, range1);
      var p2 = range2.getElement().getParent();
      temp.endIndex = body.getChildIndex(p2) + 1;
      var texts = "";
//      for (var i = temp.startIndex + 1; i < temp.endIndex - 1; i++) {
      for (var i = temp.startIndex; i < temp.endIndex; i++) {
        texts += body.getChild(i).asParagraph().getText();
      }
      temp.texts = texts;
      res.push(temp);
    }
    range1 = body.findText(pattern1, range2);
  }
  Logger.log(res)
}
```

#### Result:

When your sample values are put to new Google Document and run the script, the following result is retrieved.

```
[
  {
    "startIndex": 0,
    "endIndex": 5,
    "texts": "<li sheet=\"experiences\">{{company_name}},  {{job_location}} — {{job_title}}MONTH {{from}} - {{to}}{{description}}</li>"
  },
  {
    "startIndex": 6,
    "endIndex": 9,
    "texts": "<li sheet=\"other\">{{test}}</li>"
  }
]
```

- For above result, if you want to retrieve the values of `{{company_name}},  {{job_location}} — {{job_title}}MONTH {{from}} - {{to}}{{description}}` and `{{test}}` without the tags, please modify above script as follows.

  - From:

    ```
    for (var i = temp.startIndex; i < temp.endIndex; i++) {
    ```
  - To:

    ```
    for (var i = temp.startIndex + 1; i < temp.endIndex - 1; i++) {
    ```

#### References:

- [findText(searchPattern, from)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern,-from)
- [getChildIndex(child)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildindexchild)
- [getParent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getparent)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you very much for your answer. I will certainly use part of it, but I simplified the description of my issue to focus on 1 problem only: matching `<li>...</li>` when `...` has any character, including new lines. The regex you suggested is considered invalid by Google App Scripts. Any idea?

Comment: I might be out of luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771381/eliminate-newlines-in-google-app-script-using-regex

Comment: @Greg Forel Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue of `The regex you suggested is considered invalid by Google App Scripts.`. Because in my test, your sample values can be used with the sample script. So can you explain about the detail information of it? I would like to think of it.

Comment: sorry, your regex does work. I made a mistake using it. This is helpful to solve my problem, thanks again!