# How to detect new line within a google sheets cell using AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace, newline

I am using this [script](https://gist.github.com/florentdescroix/9513cfd957f8b2cde7b832cf7170c84a) to generate json based on my spreadsheet.

Some of my cells have a new line that no visible within a cell.
When I fun a script the new line appears like `..mytext \nMytext`, etc

I want to replace `\n` with `<br>`, so I placed that at [line 44](https://gist.github.com/florentdescroix/9513cfd957f8b2cde7b832cf7170c84a#file-exportjson-js-L44)

```
text.replace('\n', "<br>")
```

which is didn't work at all, so I've changed it to that:

```
text.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

which didn't work either, the `\n` is still present within an output.

I believe it has a different code or something, any ideas how to fix?

> The text to google sheet is copy-pasted from google docs

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `text.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");` and `which didn't work either, the \n is still present within an output.`, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
text.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

#### To:

```
text.replace(/\\n/g, "<br>")
```

- From `I want to replace \n with <br>, so I placed that at [line 44](https://gist.github.com/florentdescroix/9513cfd957f8b2cde7b832cf7170c84a#file-exportjson-js-L44)`, how about the following modification?

  ```
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<textarea style='width:100%;' rows='20'>" + text.replace(/\\n/g, "<br>") + "</textarea>");
  ```
- When I saw [your showing script](https://gist.github.com/florentdescroix/9513cfd957f8b2cde7b832cf7170c84a), at `makeJSON_`, `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);` is returned. By this, I thought that `text.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")` is required to be modified to `text.replace(/\\n/g, "<br>")`.

Comment: magic, how did you figure out that?

Comment: @sreginogemoh Thank you for replying. About `how did you figure out that?`, when I saw your showing script, at `makeJSON_` function, `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);` is returned. In this case, `\n` is converted to `\\n`. By this, I thought that `text.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")` is required to be modified to `text.replace(/\\n/g, "<br>")`.